# Finding the Area bounded by two lines and x-axis

Tags: calculus, integration, polynomials, area

Let $f$ be a function given by $f(x)=4x^2-x^3$ and let $p(x)=18-3x$ be the line tangent to graph of $f(x)$. Let $R$ be the region that bounded by the $x$-axis and graph of $f(x)$; and $S$ be the region bounded by the $x$-axis, line $p(x)$ and the graph of $f(x)$. Find the area of $S$.

So, I found the area of $R$ using the integral of $f(x)$ from 0 to 4 since those are the $x$-intercepts which is 64/3 but now I don't know what I could do to use to find the area of $S$ after this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $$(18-3x)-(4x^2-x^3)=x^3-4x^2-3x+18=$$
$$=x^3+2x^2-6x^2-12x+9x+18=(x+2)(x-3)^2,$$ we see that graphs of $f$ and $p$ are touching and the graph of $p$ placed above the graph of $f$.

Thus, the needed area is
$$\int\limits_{-2}^4(x^3-4x^2-3x+18)dx+S_{\Delta},$$
where $S_{\Delta}=\frac{(6-4)6}{2}=6.$

Can you end it now?

I got that the answer is $60$.

If you mean the area in the first quadrant then we need to delete $$\int\limits_{-2}^3(x^3-4x^2-3x+18)dx=\frac{625}{12}$$ and we'll get the following area
$$60-\frac{625}{12}=\frac{95}{12}.$$
Also, you can use the following.

Let $A(3,9)$ be a common point of our graphs in the first quadrant, $C(C,0)$ and $B(6,0)$.

Thus, for nedded area we obtain:
$$S_{\Delta ABC}-\int\limits_3^4(4x^2-x^3)dx=\frac{95}{12}.$$

Comment: The answer is 7.916 and also where did you get your boundaries 4 and -2. Kinda confused

Comment: @Bushra $(-2,24)$ and $(3,9)$ are common points of our graphs. The point $(4,0)$ it's a common point of the graph of $f$ with $x$-axis.

Comment: Okay!  That makes perfect sense, that was my fault not letting you know about the first quadrant, next time I know to minus the curves and find that common point, but thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome! I added an easier way.